# How can I select the record only on clicking the checkbox not on any cell using checkbox selection model

Tags: extjs

`checkOnly:true` property is not working for `checkboxselection` model.
Is there any way to resolve this issue

I tried creating a `beforecellclick` listener. But it is preventing the other listeners in the grid

```
beforecellclick : function(grid, td, cellIndex, record, tr, rowIndex,e,eOpts)
 {                  

 if (cellIndex !== 0) 
{
   return false;
}
}
```

I want the records to be selected only on checkbox click not on other cell clicks.

Comment: Please provide more piece of working code!

Comment: var checkBoxSelectionModel = Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel', {
           mode : 'SIMPLE',
           checkOnly:true,
            });